# Image tag in WPF in .net core 3.0 not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I am working on a WPF application using .net core 3.0 preview.

I tried the following line of `xaml` code in both `.net core 3.0 preview` and `.net framework`.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Image Source="system-tray.jpg"/>
</Grid>
```

This works fine in `.Net Framework` but doesn't work in `.Net Core 3.0 preview`

Any thoughts!..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For those coming by here in the future looking for an answer, like I did, here's the thing to check:

Make sure the Build Action for your image files in Visual Studio is set to "**Resource**". This can be checked by right-clicking the image file in the Solution Explorer and selecting "Properties".

Source: [github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/292](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/292) per question comment by Clemens

Comment: Remains completely broken by Visual Studio 16.5.4 and using .NET Core 3.1 with UseWPF == true. Build Action Resource or Content (copy always) doesn't work. Using UriKind.Relative uri. Unbelievable.